# MVC includes remnant of partial view when full view is requested

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my project I have one page that I render as a partial via an ajax call.  The target for this page is a div in my _Layout page with an id of "bodyContent" like this:

```
<div id="bodyContent">
   @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Note this is the same div where .net renders the document body.

I load my page with this small script:

```
this.loadBodyContent = function (uri) {
        return $.get(uri).done(function (data) {
            $('#bodyContent').html(data);
        });
    }
```

The uri in the script points to a method on my controller that looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        vm.Initialize();
        return PartialView(vm);
    }
```

All of this works fine until I want to navigate back to the home page.  In my page I have a button that calls a method on my controller that contains this line:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { noCache = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() });
```

This method works fine and in fact calls the Index action on the Home controller every time (i.e. it is not being cached).  Index on the Home controller looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ProcedureTreeView procedureTreeView = new ProcedureTreeView("treeview1", "");
        ViewBag.data = procedureTreeView.Render();
        return View();
    }
```

Note that Index returns a view which I believe means it should render the entire page - however when the page is rendered my partial page is rendered again in the bodyContent div and the home page is rendered after it.  So it looks like this

```
    <div id="bodyContent">
    partial page content here (this is the problem - it should not render again)
    home page content here
    </div>
```

My question is - why is the View returned from Index on the home controller not re-rendering the entire page from scratch?  How do I fix it?
This behavior is observed in both IE and Chrome.
Using MVC 5.1, .net 4.5

Edit:  additional code per request.  Here is how the partial page is posted back:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "EndUserSearch", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "searchResults" }, new { id="searchForm" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

   <div class="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

   <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">

            <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-default" />
            <input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Comment: Explain more how this button works - is it an AJAX call? A hyperlink? A full-page POST? The culprit is likely to be on the client-side (which you glossed over) because it sounds like your `Index` action is being hit by an AJAX request which is then rendering the response into `bodyContent`. It's not going to be possible to diagnose the problem with such piecemeal snippets of code.

Comment: @AntP Additional code added per your request.